# "bitwise or" works sometimes

Tags: c++, casting, bitwise-operators

**this is my problem:**

I am writing a program in QtCreator which reads out some battery data (voltage, current,...). Each value is delivered in two bytes and I have to combine them into a UINT16.
*Sometimes my program does it right* and shows the correct value (about 12V).
But *some other time it does not work* and shows about 65V. 
The problem occurs only if I have connected a load to the battery. Then it sometimes says 65V and sometimes 12V.
I have used an older program to oberserve the data I get from the battery and this data says all the time about 12V, so *it's not the data what is wrong*.

This is what I have written in my acutal program:

```
voltage = data[6] << 8;
voltage = voltage | data[7];
```

**What I have found out so far:**

The problem does NOT occur if the voltage reaches a specefic value (e.g. drops from 12.X V to 11.X V), there seems to be no system in it.

I have already converted the values I get into binary numbers to see if there is just anything swapped. This is not the case.

The old program does this, what is the same like in my actual program:

```
voltage = data[6]<<8;
voltage|= data[7];
```

EDIT:
- This is what I know about the delivered data:

Format: Unsigned int

Units:  mV

Range:  0 to 65,535 mV ==> 1000 = 1V

- For the 'voltage' variable I chose UINT16 in my new program.
- In my old code I'm using unsigned short for 'voltage'. When I change this in my new program this doesn't have an effect on my problem.

Some more information about how the program works, could be helpful maybe:

- read out buffer (14 bytes)
- check if first byte is '$' (badge for relevant data)
- check if second byte is 7 (badge for battery data)
- then do the shifting and bitwise or what I wrote above
- print result

The weirdest thing is that it works sometimes when a load is applied and if I wait for a while it does not work any more then suddenly it works again and so on, no matter what voltage.

EDIT2:

The programs are different, there is everything different except for my passage. I only work on this passage of reading the battery data / I built this area. The old program was written using MSVisual Studio 2009 C++ Express.
For the new program I'm using QtCreator with Mingw4.8 as compiler.
data[] is of type QByteArray:

In .h: 
UINT16 voltage;

In .c:

```
QByteArray data = com_port.readLine(1000);

if (data[0] == '$')
            {
                switch (data[1])
                {
                    case 7:
                       voltage  = data[6]<<8;
                       voltage  = voltage|data[7];
                       qDebug() << voltage;
                }
             }
```

The target of both programs is the same and I'm using the same battery.

Comment: the exact types of volatage/data and initialization would be helpfull. As well as the scale factor (what't the value of 1Volt). Also does the "old" code does not have this problem under load conditions?

Comment: It would be helpful to now how you initialised `voltage`. If this were an `int` instead of an `uint`, for example, you could experience problems like this.

Comment: 65 is a magic number, 2^16 = 65536.  Change the type of *data* to an unsigned type to avoid problems with sign extension.  In other words, replace *char* with *unsigned char*.

Comment: Do some debugging. Find specific values of the arguments to the operator that behave in ways that you do not understand. Don't rely on guesswork.

Comment: @AviPerel The old code does not have this problem, what makes me going crazy. It shows always the correct value, even if I apply a load to the battery.

Comment: @Malte following edit2: Could you also please provide the definition (typedef) of QByteArray ? Regarding the old program - the handling of char as signed or unsigned is compiler dependent - making the experience with the "old" program potentially irrelevant.

Comment: @Malte also please note that "voltage  = data[6]<<8", when data is some kind of 8 bit type will result in... zero. (you take an 8 bits value, shift it 8 positions to the left, shifting-in 8 zero bits - hence resulting in 8 zero bits. You then cast it to 16 bits - yielding 0.)

Comment: @AviPerel Regarding the QByteArray I could only find this: Constructs an empty byte array.

I have now splitted up the 'shifting' and the 'or' what shows that the 'or' is the problem in fact, I think.

Comment: After I splitted the 'shifting' and 'or' I found out that data[7] sometimes is very high (more than a byte). For example it was 4294967217. So I added a data[7]&0xFF so that I only get what I need, I hope. It seems to work now...hopefully I take the correct numbers wit that 0xFF, because I'm not sure, if the highest two bytes are the ones I need or if it's the lowest two. I can't explain why there can be such a big number in data[7], I thought it was a byte...

Comment: @Malte There's no big surprise here: going back to my original answer: 4294967217 = 0b11111111111111111111111110110001. So if data[7] was 0b10110001 (unsigned char value of 177), and you sign extend it to 32 bit (simply replicate the left most bit 24 more times)- you get that very large number. when you zeroed the upper bits by anding 0xff, you got your unsigned value back.

Comment: @Malte what you probably want to do (assuming data[7] is indeed the low byte of the voltage reading): unsigned int voltage =  ((((unsigned int)(data[6])) << 8) | (data[7]&0xff)) & 0xffff; you can change the unsigned int to your UINT16. You can lose some of the parentheses depending on operator priority and drop the last "&0xffff", but this is as explicit as it gets. I would also double check the scale factor and whether data[7] is indeed the low byte.

Comment: Ok, it seems to work now :)

Comment: But I don't get yet why data[7] is extended to 32 bit? I thought it would be extended to 16 bit. Is unsigned int sometimes 16 bit and sometimes 32 bit? On what does it depend how many bits the unsigned int has?

Comment: @Malte unsigned int is supposed to be AT LEAST 16 bits. This is the lower limit required, but compiler/architecture may use more, and mostly will use at least 32 bits. You need to check the typedef of UINT16 - if the old compiler was using 16bit, then it may be defined as unsigned int, making the new compiler handle it as 32 bits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my guess:
IF your data[7] is signed char (either explicitly or by your compiler handling char as signed value), and IF the scale factor is 0.1 volt, then going from 12.7 volt to 12.8 volt would make data[7] a negative value.
You then sign extend it to 16 bits (by an implied cast), hence your result value is something around 65000 - which is equal to around 6500V - similar to the 65V you seem to see (any chance there are a couple of extra zeroes?). The minute you drop to 12.7V or below - you're back to the real voltage.

For example:

12.7 volt = 0b01111111 -> (sign extend to 16 bit) -> 0b00000000 01111111 -> 127 -> 12.7 Volt

12.8 volt = 0b10000000 -> (sign extend to 16 bit) -> 0b11111111 10000000 -> 65408 -> 6540.8 Volt

This is just a hunch - as the actual types/scale factor are not provided.

EDIT:

What you probably want to do is

```
unsigned int voltage = ((((unsigned int)(data[6])) << 8) | (((unsigned int)data[7])&0xff)) & 0xffff;
```

You can change the unsigned int to your UINT16. You can lose some of the parentheses (based on operator priority) and drop the last "&0xffff", but this is as explicit as it gets.

Comment: 'voltage' is unsigned int, so I think it has nothing to do with this. This was in fact a problem when I wanted to read out the current in my old program, because current IS signed. I have therefore spent much time on converting signed/unsigned values and finally I thinks I understood this converting thing.

Comment: @Malte is voltage unsigned int or something like uint16_t ? what is the type of data - is it char ? Can you please provide the exact declarations?

Comment: In the .h-file the 'voltage' variable is declared as UINT16. In the datasheet of the battery is written that the data type is unsigned int (0-65535).

Comment: @Malte what is the type of data[] declared in the program? Can you also add the output (printf or whatever) code? Also, when referring to the "old" program - is it exactly the same program, with only the two lines shown changed? Was it compiled using the same compiler for the same target? Was it run on the same target?

Comment: I'm sorry to give you this information bit by bit I'm quite new to programming so I'm was not sure what you could need. I'll write it as edit in my first post.